# convert SelectedIndices.Item(0) from vb to c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, translation, c#-to-vb.net

I have this little row of code which i cant translate from vb to c#

```
private string _code;
private DataTable _liste;
_code = _liste.Rows(lvList.SelectedIndices.Item(0))("Name")
```

If i try "selectedindices" in c#, vs dont suggest mit the "item" property.
Is there an equivalent in c#?

Comment: what is `lvList`? `lvList.SelectedItems[0]`?

Comment: sorry, i forgot. `lvList`is the listview control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special `Item` property is VB's representation of a C# **indexer**. In C#, indexers are accessed by omitting `Item` and specifying the index in brackets:

```
lvList.SelectedIndices[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I would like to retrieve the listing of rows that belong to the table. But `_liste.Rows` doesnt seems to be the way to do it. I'm very new to C# and have big trouble with the conversion.

Comment: @klint: I suggest you start a new question about that.

Comment: I found the term i watched for: `_code = _liste.Rows[lvList.SelectedIndices[0]]["Name"];` thats it...
Sometimes i do not see the wood for the trees.
Thank you very much :)